# Extracting data from grib file based on latitude and longitude

Tags: grib

If i have a grib2 file that contains information for whole world (for some parameters) and I want to extract data from it using wgrib2 **based on latitude and longitude given by user** (client software to server). I tried following command but I am getting complete grib2 file only:

> wgrib2.exe input.grb -undefine out-box 10:90 -10:10 -grib output.grb

Please tell me where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is still the top hit on Google, so even though it is a bit old, here is a more detailed explanation.

First, you need `wgrib2` from the [National Weather Service Climate Prediction Centre](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2). (The installation of that is straightforward, but not too well explained. See [this page](https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib2/INSTALLING), or this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bruceh48/b5c67f6db6e4ee161ed6364a97c81d9f) for help.)

Next, you need to use the [lola](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/lola.html) function (for LOngitude-LAtitude grid).

You need to give `wgrib2` several arguments:

- the grib file that has the data
- the longitude information:

  - the longitude of the southwest corner of your bounding box
  - the length of the bounding box in degrees
  - the spacing of the points in this direction
- the latitude information, the same as above

  - the latitude of the southwest corner of your bounding box
  - the length of the bounding box in degrees
  - the spacing of the points in this direction
- the file name to write to
- the format of the file to write (either `bin` for binary, `text` for simple text, `spread` for spreadsheet format, or `grib` for grib2).

For example:

```
wgrib2 input.grb 220:100:1 20:50:1 output.grb2 grib
```

will create an output file that covers north america (220 E - 320 E; 20 N - 70 N) at 1 degree intervals in both directions.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command to extract information from grib2 file.

> `wgrib2.exe input_file.grib2 -lola LonSW:#lon:dlon LatSW:#lat:dlat file format`

assuming that we are having following co-ordinates for selection:

> > Top: (x0,y0) (x1,y0)
> >
> > Bottom: (x0,y1) (x1,y1)
>
> "LongSW"=x0, #lon = (x0~x1), "LatSW"=y0, #lat = (y0~y1).
>   and dlon and dlan can be kept as 1. 'file' is the output file name and format can be grib, csv, text etc.

Substitute above values in the command shown above and you should get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your chosen longitude was 360 and latitude was 90:

wgrib2.exe input_file.grb2 -lon 360 90 > output_file.txt

Comment: Do you know how to save this as CSV rather than txt? Adding the `-csv` doesn't restrict the file to the lat/lon that were passed.

Comment: to output to CSV:
    wgrib2 intput.grb -s -irr_grid -121.4170309:47.45871 20 - | wgrib2 - -csv output.csv

Comment: This @ScottChamberlin should be an accepted answer.  -ijsmall_grib instead of if -irr_gird if you really mean to "extract" not to have interpolation by wgrib2

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use cdo directly on grib for this

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in.grb out.grb
```

If the grib file is on a reduced gaussian grid you may need to specify that you want a regular lat-lon output.  I usually convert the output format to netcdf myself using "-f nc" as I find it easier to process in other software.